# How to add software icon to Indicators panel?

Tags: 16.04, icons, indicator

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 and have xfce4-indicator-plugin for indicator panel.Some programs as f.ex. Xpad and Time Tracker have their application icons displayed in this panel, when running.Like this:[image]

But for others only this icon appears:
[image]

Is it possible to add somewhere image for the indicator plugin to take from for those aplications, that don't have it by default and if yes, how could I do that?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, it's not always possible, because it depends on the programming language in which indicator is written, so your best approach would be to file a bug report to the developers of that application.

Here's what I mean in more detail. If the indicator is written in one of the scripting languages, such as python,perl, or ruby, then you can edit that file. Of course , you'd have to know what to edit. I write mostly in python, and in that case, the icon name is typically set in the class declaration, for example from one of mine:

```
class UdisksIndicator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = appindicator.Indicator.new(
            'udisks-indicator', "drive-harddisk-symbolic.svg",
```

Here you see that "drive-harddisk-symbolic.svg" is the icon name.
So you could easily edit that.

If the indicator is written in one of the compiled languages, such as C , Vala, or Java , then you can't change it - the indicator is a fixed binary, so you'd have to have source code, and know how to recompile that source code.

It also depends largely on the type of icon the indicator uses. It may be a custom icon that came with package. In that case, you could look into `/var/lib/dpkg/info/package_name.list` file ( which is created for every package you install with `apt` or `dpkg` ), figure out which one of the files on the list is the icon that is supposed to be displayed for that indicator, and perhaps replace that specific file with your own. That of course only masks the symptops and doesn't treat the issue. If you were to reinstall and run into the same problem again, you don't want to keep doing icon replacement over and over. Worse yet, if the icon uses one of the standard icons that are supposed to be on the system. For instance, there's whole bunch of standard icons in `/usr/share/icons/gnome` , and I personally use those a lot.If such icons fail, then there's some large issue going on.  That's another argument for filing bug report.

And as I've mentioned before, you'd have to know *where* to change the setting, if you were to edit file on your own. Chances also are that you're not the only one having such issue. It's in your and other people's benefit to submit a bug report and let developers fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I was hoping, that it's easier to accomplish. I guess, I have to live with no ap icons for some programs.